# Href not working when im logged in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I did the authentication system and when i'm logged in the Hyperlinks are not working anymore and when i put the cursor on it , it shows the correct path that it will be rendered to . 
When i change the URL from browser's URL bar it goes to the page i want...

views.py

```
def request_view(request):
  return render(request, 'admin/request_form.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('request/', views.request_view, name='request_form'),
```

Comment: Hi @MedAziz11, can you be more specific about your question? Show us some of your workings, what you tried and what failed?

Comment: here it is ... btw when im in login page or signup page the hyperlinks are working.

Comment: If you would add a namespace `administration`, the resulting url will be "/administration/request" but from your `urls.py`, I think you don't need a namespace.
Try `<a href="{% url 'request_form' %}">form </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the path in href like below. It should do the trick for you

```
<a href="/request/">form </a>
```

Comment: Try to explain your issue in understandable English sentence. This is not your whatsapp chat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will work

```
<a href="{% url 'request_form' %}">form </a>
```

Comment: still not i think its cuz of security or smthing cuz when im not logged in th hyperlinks r working well

Comment: can you explain a bit more?